# React native app stuck on white screen without any errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am learning React native and was trying to build an app. However, the app is stuck on a white screen and doesn't show anything nor gives any error. This code is going to render a flatlist from an array and will have a delete to swipe button on the right. I am not getting any errors though.

[image]

Message.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  ItemSeparatorComponent,
  Platform
} from 'react-native'

import ListItem from '../components/ListItem'
import ListItemSeparator from '../components/ListItemSeparator'
import DeleteSwipe from '../components/DeleteSwipe'
const messages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'T1',
    description: 'D2',
    image: require('../assets/mosh.jpg')
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'T2',
    description: 'D2',
    image: require('../assets/mosh.jpg')
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'T3',
    description: 'D3',
    image: require('../assets/mosh.jpg')
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'T4',
    description: 'D4',
    image: require('../assets/mosh.jpg')
  }
]
export default function Message () {
  const [messages, setMessage] = useState(messages)

  const handleDelete = messages => {
    const newMessages = messages.filter(m => m.id != messages.id)
    setMessage(newMessages)
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <FlatList
        data={messages}
        keyExtractor={messages => messages.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListItem
            name={item.name}
            description={item.description}
            image={item.image}
            onPress={() => console.log('touched', item)}
            renderRightActions={() => (
              <DeleteSwipe onPress={() => handleDelete(item)} />
            )}
          />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
      />

      <FlatList />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    padding: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
  }
})
```

DeleteSwipe.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable'
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const DeleteSwipe = props => {
  const { renderRightActions } = props
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={console.log('delete it')}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AntDesign name='delete' size={24} color='white' />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 70,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ff5252'
  }
})

export default DeleteSwipe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If it is a debugger issue, Restart the debugger if react native debugger is running. and again start
2. Or it could be a flexbox issue, Try to add or remove `display: flex` and `flex:1` on this and parent.
3. Or it could be component is too small, Open inspector from dev menu and check component names in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change onPress={console.log....} to onPress={() => console.log(...
)}

But it seems what you want is onPress={props.onPress}